# Running .exe on a XAMPP Server

Tags: xampp, exe

I am wondering if it is possible to run a program on a xampp server? I am making a game and need to run the controller program on the server to receive info from the client programs. Is this possible? I do know that you can start a program on a server remotely, but it opens the program on the server pc, not what I am wanting.

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to click and link on a index.php page and that opens the client.exe on your pc. So far, it only launches it on the server pc. I am using the echo exec('') command to launch the program.

Thanks,
DogLover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side you can try either PHP/CGI and stores the data in a file or a MySQL database.

On client side you can try either JAVA/Flash or you can force the download of file on user computer using `content disposition` in header.